# Issue with Sorting by Price in 'Products in Category' Section of Magento Admin

Tags: magento2.4.5

I am using Magento version 2.4.5 and I've encountered a specific issue in the Magento admin panel that I'd like to discuss.

When I navigate to the 'Products in Category' section of any category and view the products under "ALL STORE VIEWS", all the products from all website views are displayed as expected initially. I've attached a screenshot for reference (See: Image 1).

However, when I attempt to sort these products by price, a peculiar behavior is observed:

After sorting by price, it seems that only products associated with the default website view are being displayed and sorted. I've included a screenshot of this behavior for clarity (See: Image 2).

For instance, if there's a product, say Product A, that is exclusively associated with a non-default website, it doesn't show up in the sorted list at all, despite being visible before sorting.

My hypothesis is that when sorting by price under "ALL STORE VIEWS", Magento might be unsure which website view's price to consider for a product. As a result, it might default to using the price from the default website view. This could potentially explain why only products from the default website view are displayed post-sorting.

Could you confirm if this is an intended behavior or a known issue in Magento? If it's not the intended behavior, could you guide me on possible solutions or workarounds? Also, is there any official documentation or acknowledged issues related to this in Magento's resources?

I look forward to your insights and assistance.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]